# Error using paho-mqtt x64 using vcpkg in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, paho, vcpkg

I have installed paho-mqttpp3:x64-windows using vcpkg and running the below code in Visual Studio with build option in x64.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mqtt/async_client.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

When I am running above code it generate following error

```
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(85):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(85):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(85):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(85):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(109):
> error C3646: 'data': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(109):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(110):
> error C3646: 'value': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(110):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(123):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(123):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(123):
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(141):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(141):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(141):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(141):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(141):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '*'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(164):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(164):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(164):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(164):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(171):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(171):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(171):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(171):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier
> 'MQTTProperties'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(179):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(179):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(179):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(179):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(188):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(188):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(188):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(188):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(196):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(196):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(196):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(196):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(206):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(206):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(206):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(206):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(214):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(214):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(214):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(214):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier
> 'MQTTProperty'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(223):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(223):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(223):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(223):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier
> 'MQTTProperty'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttreasoncodes.h(83):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttreasoncodes.h(83):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttreasoncodes.h(83):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttreasoncodes.h(83):
> error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(223):
> error C3646: 'popen': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(223):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(227):
> error C3646: 'pclose': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(227):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(231):
> error C3646: 'pput': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(231):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(235):
> error C3646: 'pget': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(235):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(239):
> error C3646: 'premove': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(239):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(243):
> error C3646: 'pkeys': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(243):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(247):
> error C3646: 'pclear': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(247):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(251):
> error C3646: 'pcontainskey': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttclientpersistence.h(251):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(233):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(233):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(233):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(233):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(233):
> error C2065: 'MQTTAsync_init_options': undeclared identifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(233):
> error C2065: 'inits': undeclared identifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(233):
> error C2182: 'MQTTAsync_global_init': illegal use of type 'void'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(346):
> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'MQTTAsync_message'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(366):
> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'MQTTAsync_token'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(424):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(424):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(424):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(424):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(424):
> error C2065: 'MQTTAsync': undeclared identifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(424):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'handle'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(431):
> error C3646: 'token': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(431):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(447):
> error C3646: 'token': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(447):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(466):
> error C3646: 'token': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(466):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(477):
> error C3646: 'message': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(477):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(497):
> error C3646: 'token': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(497):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(512):
> error C3646: 'message': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(512):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(543):
> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'MQTTAsync_successData'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(556):
> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'MQTTAsync_successData5'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(568):
> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'MQTTAsync_failureData'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(580):
> error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'MQTTAsync_failureData5'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(594):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(594):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(594):
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(600):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(600):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(600):
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(612):
> error C3646: 'token': unknown override specifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(612):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(618):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(618):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(618):
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(624):
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(624):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(624):
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(677):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(677):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(677):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(677):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(677):
> error C2065: 'MQTTAsync': undeclared identifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(677):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'handle'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(700):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(700):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(700):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(700):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(700):
> error C2065: 'MQTTAsync': undeclared identifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(700):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'handle'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(724):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(724):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(724):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(724):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(724):
> error C2065: 'MQTTAsync': undeclared identifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(724):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'handle'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(746):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(746):
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
> support default-int
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(746):
> error C2374: '__attribute__': redefinition; multiple initialization
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttproperties.h(67):
> note: see declaration of '__attribute__'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(746):
> error C2448: '__attribute__': function-style initializer appears to be
> a function definition
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(746):
> error C2065: 'MQTTAsync': undeclared identifier
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(746):
> error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'handle'
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(761):
> error C3861: 'visibility': identifier not found
> 1>d:\vcpkg\packages\paho-mqtt_x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt\mqttasync.h(761):
> fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

But when I installed paho-mqttpp3:x86-windows using vcpkg and running the same code in Visual Studio with build option in x86. **It get successfully run.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mqtt/async_client.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

OS - Windows 10 64 bit Home

Visual Studio - 15.9.19

paho-mqtt installed using vcpkg.

Comment: `__attribute__` is a special extension of the GCC and Clang compilers, Visual Studio doesn't have those. So there seems to be some misconfigurations in your installation of the `paho-mqttpp3:x64-windows` package. If it's on your side, or a mistake by the package maintainers (or elsewhere) I don't know.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue is that you have to change few things in MQTT files.

Changes to be done in the content of the following file which is inside **paho-mqtt** folder. In my case it is inside **D:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt**

MQTTAsync

MQTTClient

MQTTProperties

MQTTReasonCodes

In all the above file change the following content.

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
  #define DLLImport __declspec(dllimport)
  #define DLLExport __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define DLLImport extern
  #define DLLExport  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#endif
```

> Macro WIN32 and WIN64 should be changed to _WIN32 and _WIN64

You will find it like this:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
```

Change to

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
```

> OR

**Note: Don't follow below steps if you had already followed above procedure.**

You can add **WIN64** in your **Preprocessor Directory** of your projects property of Visual Studio.

Go-to   Solution Explorer --> Properties --> C/C++ --> Preprocessor.

Add **WIN64** inside **Preprocessor Directory**